# SQL - Get record where 2 of N words match

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, full-text-search, where-clause

We have a SQL Server 2008 Database table: **Companies**

Company names can be complex like **St. Charles Ltd / Hospice Center**

If the name provided meets **both** criteria:

- consists of 3 or more words
- at least three words are 4 characters are longer

Then the name will get cleansed, and passed to my SQL SP.

Cleansing the name involves removing non-alpha characters, and also abbreviations such as INC,CORP,LTD,LLC,CO,etc..

Using the example above, my SP would then receive: **Charles Hospice Center**

**My Goal** is to use SQL to return any records that match

```
Charles Center
Center Hospice
Hospice Charles
Charles Hospice
Hospice Center
```

I could manually split each word out.....

```
WHERE Name like '%Charles%Center%' or 
      Name like '%Center%Charles%' or
      Name like '%Hospice%Charles%' 
   etc.. etc.. etc..
```

But if 4 words are provided, then I'm writing out 24 combinations... and thought there might be an easier method, or even a SQL function already available for something like this?

---

**  **EDIT** **

Full Text Search (from some online reading) appears to a great solutions.  I'm just not certain of how to specify 2 of X words must match... or really how to use it correctly.  Examples would be great!

Comment: you are on the right track... actually if you did `Name like '%Charles%' or name like '%Hospice%' or name like '%Center%'` it would give you all of them

Comment: @logixologist but I only want records that match at least 2 of the words.

Comment: Look into full text search.  It should have the capabilities you are looking for.

Comment: very interesting problem.., You may have to do it your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string function like

```
where (CHARINDEX('Charles', Name) > 0 and CHARINDEX('Center', Name) > 0)
OR
(CHARINDEX('Hospice', Name) > 0 and CHARINDEX('Center', Name) > 0)
OR
(CHARINDEX('Hospice', Name) > 0 and CHARINDEX('Charles', Name) > 0)
```

**(OR)**

As suggested by @gordon you can use Fulltext search.

Use [CONTAINS (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) like

```
where contains(Name,' Charles AND Center ')
OR
contains(Name,' Charles AND Hospice ')
OR
contains(Name,' Hospice AND Center ')
```

**(OR)**

Use [FREETEXT (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx) like

```
where FREETEXT(Name,' "Charles and Center')
    OR
    FREETEXT(Name,' Charles AND Hospice ')
    OR
    FREETEXT(Name,' Hospice AND Center ')
```

In both cases of `contains` and `freetext` it assumes your `Name` column is `full-text indexed`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will return records that match ANY of the 3 given words.  I only want records that match AT LEAST 2 of the provided words.

Comment: Nice!  I will give this a shot right now and try it.